# PHPSECLIB Ansi is very slow

Tags: php, phpseclib

I noticed my code was running very slow. So I did a buffer stream to figure out where it is using echo and numbers. Getting to echo 3 is very fast but echo 3 to echo 4 takes seconds. I stripped out all the code leaving a SSH con and the ANSI

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('File/ANSI.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($HostName, $Port);
if (!$ssh->login($ADID, $UnixPass)) {
exit('Login Failed');
}
ob_implicit_flush();
$ansi = new File_ANSI();
echo "3";
@$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
echo @$ansi->getScreen();
echo "4";
```

Any idea how to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

When `$ssh->read()` doesn't have any parameters it'll just read until it hits the timeout (which is, by default, 10 seconds). Two solutions exist:

1. Do `$ssh->read('username@username:~$');`, changing `username@username:~$` out with the prompt.
2. Do `$ssh->setTimeout(2);`. eg. set the timeout to less than what you're getting. Like 2 seconds or something idk

Comment: This is exactly what i needed and shaved a lot of time off. is it possible to do something like read ('username@username:~$' || 'username@username:~>')?

Comment: @MoonEater916 - `$ssh->read('#username@username:~\$|username@username:~>#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX)` should do the trick.

Comment: `$ssh->read('#username@username:~[\$>]#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX)` would be more concise.